# Ipi - interprocess interrupt latency

Tags: x86-64, interrupt, latency

- Cpus: Intel, amd.
- Arch : x86_64.

I have hard time measuring / finding resource about Interprocessor Interrupts latency.

It will depend on the processor, the apic version but I am talking about the order of magnitude here.

Should I expect something in the µsec, tenth of µsec, lower / higher ?

If someone could give me a hint, I would really appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Get a scope, and find something that you can write to which will trigger the scope and measure it, write it high when you issue the IPI, then write it low when you get into the ISR.

Comment: yep. Will try that. Thanks

Comment: Could you measure in software by measuring the round-trip time?  `rdtsc` (start time) on one CPU, send an IPI, and `rdtsc` (stop time) in an IPI handler.  On the other CPU, you have a different IPI handler that sends an IPI back to the first CPU.

Comment: That is a nice idea ! Will do that. I just hope it will not be to high now :)